# WP - Check if current site matches site_id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to check if the current MU site_id is 389 or 545 and then load the custom fonts file.

This is my attempt to check if either of the 2 site_id's provided match what is in the `$site_id` variable. No errors returned, it's just not matching and not loading the file. Anything obviously wrong?

```
$site_id = get_current_blog_id();

if( $site_id == array('389', '545') ) {
      wp_enqueue_style('sage/custom-fonts.css', asset_path('styles/custom-fonts.css'), false, null);
    }
```

This works fine:

```
if( $site_id == '389' ) {
```

But I want to check multiple ID's.

Comment: Use `in_array()` method

Comment: @TamilvananN Ah ok I presume if( in_array('389', $site_id) ) { then but the $site_id is a string not array, bit confused here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try the below code.

```
$site_id = get_current_blog_id(); // Returns Integer
$site_id_arr = array('389', '545');
if( in_array($site_id,$site_id_arr)) {
    wp_enqueue_style('sage/custom-fonts.css', asset_path('styles/custom-fonts.css'), false, null);
}
```

Ref:

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

[get_current_blog_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id)

Comment: Note. `$site_id_arr ==` should only have one `=`

Comment: Yeah, changed. Thanks.